# Database design optimal performance

Tags: sql, database

I have problem with building a good database design. 
Article 1 has permission group 1,2,3

A user is in permission group 2 and 4

So this user should se article 1. But can I design an sql not to use OR in this case.

What if there is millions of article, that wouldent be good with an OR.

Tabel article
Articleid
Name

Table permissions
Id
Articleid
PermissionGroup

Table userpermission
Id
Userid
Permissiongroup

Something like this.

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Comment: Sorry, i have done it now. I can change the table structure I just want the best way to do this.

Comment: Is there any moore info that I should add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to tell exactly what you are trying to do with the limited details you have provided, but you should be able to `JOIN` the tables to get whether a user can access an article:

```
select u.username,
  p.articleId
from users u
inner join userpermission up
  on u.userid = up.userid
inner join permissions p
  on up.permissiongroup = p.permissiongroup
inner join articles a
  on p.articleid = a.articleid
```

Using the JOIN you will return the user and the articles they can access based on the permissions.

Comment: Is this a fast sql to run when there is millions of article and hundreds of permissiongroup on one article.

Comment: @user1199595 if you have proper indexing then you should be fine.